# present contiunuous in a present perfect sentence

Tags: tense

https://edition.cnn.com/2019/01/17/politics/trump-north-korea-kim-yong-chol-trip/index.html

> Since that time Trump has insisted that talks with North Korea **are**
>   **yielding** progress, pointing to the lack of missile and nuclear tests
>   as evidence that Pyongyang is moving towards denuclearization.

Why is there this usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to express a change that is happening gradually. For example, you have been quite ill, but you are getting better. Something that happens slowly, over a period of time.